# Estimate the volume of the shaded region

Tags: geometry

We are given two concentric circular cylinders of length L , and assume that the inner radius is 0.3 cm and the outer radius is 0.307 cm. Estimate the volume of the shaded region

[image]

I am using the formula for volume for cylinder and i plan on subtracting the larger region minus the smaller region but I noticed that we are given Length when I need height. So does anyone know how I would approach this problem?

Comment: What is the length of a cylinder, if not the height?

Comment: Length, width, breadth, depth, height. For real 3D objects, you simply need the 3 dimensions. Don't get hung up on the exact words you expect when a problem uses a different word, but the image is clear. I agree, the preferred word is height, but I could just as easily have called it dimension X so long as what I'm referencing is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required volume$=\pi{l}[(.307)^2-(.3)^2]$
therefore the nearest estimate  will be $\frac{\pi{l}[(.307)^2-(.3)^2)]}{\pi{l}[(.307)^2}=1-\frac{3^2}{.307^2}$

sir if someone says what is the length without giving you any clue you got to say it is half of full length of the bridge.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the OP's concern that they have length, when they really need height. Perhaps you could explain why they do indeed have the required information?